# how do i create pattern that goes like + and then in the next line -+ and then next line +-+?

Tags: python, loops

i used

```
n = 5
for i in range (n) :
 for j in range (i+1) :
  print("+" , end="")
  print()
```

but the code print `+-` in the line 1, but I want to print `+` then `-+` then `+-+`

please give me advice, I'm beginner in this "for type" I was start if Elif but then suddenly the assignment change to for, and I don't have basic (I mean I don't know how to print the pattern, the only thinks that print out is `+` in the first line. I want `-` in line two)

Comment: sorry, but that's not what I mean. The pattern putput goes like : 
+
-+
+-+ but in =end

Comment: Why not: `print('+', '-+, '+-+', sep='\n')`?

Comment: Hi there, do you need it to continue further, or just stop there? Think about any patterns you can find in the series - how does the series work if you extend it to the fourth step, or fifth, or 20th step?

Comment: we must use for (I) in range, the n pattern must follow the n
example : n = 10
for I in range(n):
  for j in range(I) :
   print("+-" , "\n")

but the question want the pattern to + then in the line two to ten -+ line three  +-+

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. We don't really give advice here; questions need to be specific, but it looks like you need more general help. Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341), which has tips like, if you don't have the skills to tackle a problem, going back to your teacher or learning resources.

Comment: I continued the step further, but the problem is when the pattern first line in every output is +

Comment: BTW, `range i` is not valid. Make sure you're providing the right code. For reference see [mre].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```py
lines = 10
pattern = '+-'
for i in range(1, lines+1):
    s = pattern * int((i+1)/2)
    # i=1 --> (i+1)/2 = 1 --> s = '+-', need to remove last char
    # i=2 --> int((i+2)/2) = 1 --> s = '+-', need to reverse the order of the string
    if len(s) > i: # if the length of s is bigger than the line number
        print(s[:-1])
    else:
        print(s[::-1])
```

---

If you have to use a `nested for` structure you can do something like that:

```
n = 5
for i in range (1, n+1) :
    for j in range (int((i+1)/2)) :
        print('-' if i%2 == 0 or j > 0 else '', end="+")
    print()
```

output:

```
+
-+
+-+
-+-+
+-+-+
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, but my "teacher" use hacker rank for it. And he said we should follow him to use for I in range. the code running, but still he want us to use his code

Answer (score -1):

Use a *boolean* to toggle from `+` to `-`.

```py
a = True
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        print('+' if a else '-', end='')
        a = not a
    if i % 2: a = True
    print()
```

Output

```
+
-+
+-+
-+-+
+-+-+
-+-+-+
+-+-+-+
-+-+-+-+
+-+-+-+-+
-+-+-+-+-+
```